# How to filter dataframe for specific values in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, optimization

I have a data frame. 2 cols with value:

```
A  B
1  3
4  2
2  5
6  3
-  -
4  4
```

or

```
A  B
1  3
4  2
2  5
6  3
0  0
4  4
```

Sometimes I got zeros as gaps, sometimes `-`.

I wrote a script to process that files. Part of it is deleting rows with gaps. No matter it is `0` or `-`. 
I wrote something like that:

```
df = df[df[0] != '-'] 
df = df[df[1] != '-'] 
df = df[df[0] != '0'] 
df = df[df[1] != '0']
```

And I got a df without 0 and -.
But I think it's not the best code. If I good understand I waste memory creating copies of df.

How should I wrote code like this (on this example) to do it right and good? Can someone share advice?

Comment: `df[~(df.eq('-').all(1)|df.eq(0).all(1))]`

Comment: @anky_91 that is just a superb one-liner which I think best posted as an answer, albeit a short one.

Comment: Thank u for an answer, can U explain me it in few words? I suppose its equals two cols? And do exactly what I doing in 4 lines above but one time?

Comment: @CozyAzure thank you posted as an answer. :)

Comment: How do you load the data? Is it from CSV? If so, you could use the na_values parameter when importing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create 2 boolean masks with a `|` operator which checks if all the columns in a row is either `-` or `0` using [`df.eq()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) and [`df.all()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) over `axis=1`:

```
df[~(df.eq('-').all(1)|df.eq(0).all(1))]
```

---

```
   A  B
0  1  3
1  4  2
2  2  5
3  6  3
5  4  4
```

Comment: @Artur: after doing this, it's probably worth also to have a 2nd look at the data types. Because according to your example the data is numeric except for the "-" gaps, so your datatype is most likely object, which uses more memory for one and is not that performant for second. After cleaning you can fix such things.

Comment: @jottbe thank u for the tip. In the post, i got only example. Usually, i got a table mixed string and ints. But I will remember that it happens I got one type :)